# How can I protect my slate floor from essential oils?

Tags: tile

I set slate tiles in my bathroom floor and counter top.  I notice that where essential oils (aroma therapy types) have dropped on the surface, the shine is gone and the sealer appears to have been eroded.

I sealed the surfaces with several coats of run of the mill sealer from the home improvement store.

Is there something better to apply over the existing sealer?

Answer (score 1):

If the cheap sealant was water based then you can top that with another water based sealant, but I don't think that would solve the problem. The essential oils are eating away the water based coating. You will need to chemically strip the old coating then coat with a penetrating sealant that says it protects against oils.

> In general, putting a solvent-based sealer on top of a water-based sealer is a bad idea. The solvents can eat or soften the existing water-based sealer, destroying both coatings. Think of it along the lines of oil and water; they do not mix.
>
> If you do want to switch to a solvent-based sealer, you will need to chemically strip off the existing water-based sealer before applying the solvent-based product.
> [Source](http://www.concretenetwork.com/fix-concrete-sealing/compatibility-water-solvent-based-sealers.html)